# Progressive loading of JSTree on node open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I'm trying to progressively load a tree of nodes using [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) - at the moment I have a root node based on some path to it with full data and child nodes with their name and path to them. I need to change the data in them (load full data) when a user opens the node. That means that my JSON at first looks like this:

```
{
"data":"Parent",
"attr":{"id:":"103.510.1.4556314","name:":"Parent"},
"children":[{
    "data":"Child_1",
    "attr":{"name":"Child_1","path":"/my/path/Child1"},
    "children":[]
        },
        "data":"Child_2",
    "attr":{"name":"Child_2","path":"/my/path/Child2"},
    "children":[]
        }]
}
```

And upon opening of Child_2 should load full data from the source again for that node. Afterwards it should look for example like this:

```
{
"data":"Parent",
"attr":{"id:":"103.510.1.4556314","name:":"Parent"},
"children":[{
    "data":"Child_1",
    "attr":{"name":"Child_1","path":"/my/path/Child1"},
    "children":[]
        },
        "data":"Child_2",
    "attr":{"name":"Child_2","id":"103.510.1.4523317"},
    "children":[{
        "data":"GrandChild_1",
        "attr":{"name":"Child_1","path":"/my/path/Child2/GrandChild1"},
            "children":[]
            },
            "data":"GrandChild_2",
        "attr":{"name":"Child_2","path":"/my/path/Child2/GrandChild2"},
        "children":[]
            }]
        }]
}
```

**How can I achieve this functionality please?**

This is my Ajax call:

```
function getJSONData(key) {

    var test;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/services/jstree?key=" + key,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (json) {
            test = json;
        },

        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
            test = "error";
        }
    });
    return test;
}
```

It's used while creating the tree:

```
$(".tree-search").click(function () {
    var jsonData = getJSONData($(this).attr("path"));
    treeContainer = $(this).siblings('.tree-container');
    treeContent = treeContainer.children('.tree-content');
    treeContent.jstree({
        "json_data": {"data": jsonData},
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox"]
    });
});
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You'd probably want to set up a jsFiddle, complete with HTML and mockup Ajax requests, of what you currently have.

Comment: @Tomalak I almost have the code necessary to achieve what I want, so I'll probably skip that and post the answer shortly. Thanks for your attention though!

Comment: I have a few remarks that are relevant but don't amount to a full answer (because that's not possible without seeing more of your code). Anyway. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it do what I needed with this binding:

```
.bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
                children = data.inst._get_children(data.rslt.obj);
                for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
                    data.inst.create_node(data.rslt.obj, "inside", getJSONData(children[i].getAttribute('path')));
                    data.inst.delete_node(children[i]);
                }
            });
```

But it looks like a hack and can probably be done better in a more "clean" way. I will gladly reassign the correct andswer if anyone comes up with a better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, you never, *never*, **never** use `async: false` Ajax requests. This feature does not exist. Use callback functions.

Next, you must not use JavaScript variables without declaring them properly with `var`. Forgetting `var` results in global variables, something that almost always can be classified as a bug.

Third you probably want event delegation, as your sub-tree elements are created dynamically and still should react to the same events.

```
// read jQuery docs on Deferred to find out about fail() and done() etc.
function getJSONData(key) {
    return $.get("/services/jstree", {key: key})
        .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
        });
    });
}

// delegate "click" event handling to the document
$(document).on("click", ".tree-search", function () {
    var key = $(this).attr("path");

    getJSONData(key).done(function (jsonData) {
        // call jstree() with jsonData
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the provided advice, I find it very useful. However the code for the child loading isn't what I need, but it's my fault of not stating my problem clearly enough probably. Thanks!